# RedHat Network - Unable to register

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to register my RedHat machine to my RedHat Network account but when I try, I get this error:

```
Problem registering system:

Error Class Code: 70
Error Class Info: 
     All available subscriptions for the requested channel have been exhausted.
     Please contact a Red Hat Network Sales associate.
Explanation: 
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.
```

Can someone help me? I don't understand everything in Linux, I'm a beginner and I want to test CPanel in local...

Answer (score 1):

A solution found in RedHat's website:

http://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-install-list/2008-March/msg00026.html

> 1. Go to http://rhn.redhat.com and login
> 2. Click on the Systems link in the red bar at the
>        top of the page.
> 3. Click on the name of the system, then click the
>       'delete system' link in the upper right of the
>        page, then 'delete profile' in the bottom right
>        of the subsequent page.
>
> You may then register the entitlement to the new system.  To register
>   your system with RHN:
>
> 1. Open up a terminal window on the system you are
>        registering.
> 2. Make sure you are logged in as root.
> 3. Enter the command `up2date --register` (for
>        versions 3 and 4) or rhn_register (for versions
>        2.1 and 5)
> 4. This should bring up an interface that will
>        guide you through the up2date process.
>
>    Make sure not to enter a subscription number when
>        you are prompted to, instead select the option
>        "Use one of my existing subscriptions" or "I do
>        not have a subscription number."
>
>    If you are trying to register version 4, we are
>        currently working on a bug with sending the
>        hardware information so please do not send the
>        hardware information.
> 5. If you would like to send your hardware profile
>        information after you have registered your
>        system with Red Hat Network you can do so by
>        opening up a terminal window, logging in as root,
>        and entering the command `up2date --hardware`.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't see my system in the list...

Answer (score 0):

- Login at https://access.redhat.com/home
- goto "Subscriptions" and then click "Entitlements"
- find your system and click the name
- in the upper right corner you will see "delete system" click and confirm

After these steps your system is removed from RHN and you can register a new one or re-register.

Comment: This seems to be the same as the first answer (more than a year older than yours) but with a slightly different URL and less detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because the other answers didn't work for you, it seems other systems are using your subscription.  In the Systems list, are there any *other* systems that can be deleted to make room for your system?

If not, then you will have to contact the Red Hat sales associate to increase the number of systems on that subscription.